# Expose a global command to run a script from node package

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line

I am building an npm package and I want it to run with its own command.

Let's say my package's name is **hello-world** and it has a script named **start** in the package.json that runs:

```
node index.js
```

What I would like is from the command line to be able to write some custom command that will run this script.

For instance, writing `hello-world` in the `cmd` will do `npm run start`.

A good example is the *nodemon* package.

Comment: like https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm ?

Comment: like [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will have to add `bin` field into your package.json to expose a global command which can be linked to any executable file(like js file).

**Sample package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "hello-world cli client",
  "bin": "index.js"
}
```

then your npm module should globally installed in your system as follows

```
npm pack (Optional.required only for local development)


npm install -g hello-world-1.0.0.tgz
```

Now you should able to run your script by just running the command as `hello-world`

**Note:** The executable script i.e `index.js` should starts with a line `#!/usr/bin/env node`

Answer (score -1):

Add an entry in your package.json under, for example

```
"scripts": {
    "runme": "node index.js"
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
npm run runme
```

Comment: what I want is to write "runme" in the command line and it will do npm run runme

Comment: Then you need to create an alias to the 'node index.js'  command on the host system. Linux, Mac, Windows all have ways of doing this.

Search for "How to add an alias to a command in terminal?" to give you some ideas